# Show columns as percentage in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I need help with a graph I am trying to built in R.

This is the data:

| Location | Total Number of Employees | Local Number | Remote Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 150 | 50 | 100 |
| L2 | 355 | 148 | 207 |
| L3 | 477 | 106 | 371 |
| L4 | 234 | 82 | 152 |
| L5 | 987 | 523 | 464 |
| L6 | 4564 | 2504 | 2060 |
| L7 | 2342 | 1425 | 917 |
| L8 | 754 | 415 | 339 |

And this is what I am aiming for
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoVxL.jpg

So, basically I want to present the "Total Number of Employees" column in a 0-100% range and since L6 has the highest number of employees, 4564 should be 100%. The legend should show the local and remote number, where the "Local" column should be shown in the positive grid and the "Remote" column in the negative one. The locations should be ordered from min to max.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what are your programming problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(Local.Number:Remote.Number, ~ .x / max(Total.Number.of.Employees)),
         Remote.Number = -Remote.Number) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Location, Total.Number.of.Employees)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Location, y = value, fill = name) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_percent()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]